Uncertainty principle probability
How are positional probabilities and momentum probabilities determined in the principle of uncertainty?
For example, if the position probability is 30, does it work like the momentum probability is 70. Or does it work in a different way of calculating?

Do you know how the variance of a probability distribution is defined and computed as? Otherwise, you do not know enough to start understanding what it is you are asking about.

I learned about the variance of probability distributions in high school. I wanted to know how to apply this to the principle of uncertainty.

Then you should have used that in writing your question. The variance defines the standard deviation, and then you can state the uncertainty principle as in DanielFBest's answer, namely that the standard deviations of position and of momentum, multiplied together, must be bigger than a constant. So then if your probability distribution tells you one of them with a smaller spread, smaller uncertainty, the other one must have a bigger spread.

Thank you and sorry. My question was ambiguous.

With the uncertainty principle in quantum mechanics, there is indeed an inherent  trade-off between the precision of the position and momentum measurements of a particle. However, it is not a simple matter of distribution in which the sum of probabilities is equal to 100. It operates instead based on the "standard deviations" of the position and momentum distributions.
The equation
$$\Delta x\, \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
means the more precisely position is known, the less precisely you can know momentum, and conversely.
The wave function will give the likelihood of finding the particle at a certain position with a certain momentum. The uncertainties in position and momentum are therefore not expressed simply as probabilities summed to 100, but if you measure position with high precision, the momentum distribution will be more spread out, and conversely.
The wave functions govern the probabilities in position and momentum spaces, and this relates their precisions, not the direct probabilities.
